# Allowing * in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure and I want to allow * in it so that if user:

- types t* then taller, tea returns
- types * or *.* then all results are returned
- types t then all results which have t are returned like ptv, tall, sit

my stored procedure is this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchEntityDataNew]
    @SearchText varchar(100) = '*'

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Entity' as pagetype,EntityID,EntityData,EntityDataID 
    FROM EntityData 
    WHERE  EntityData LIKE '%' + @SearchText+ '%'
    OR @SearchText = '*'

    union all

    SELECT 'Property' as pagetype,PropertyID,PropertyValue,EntityDataID  
    FROM EntityDataProperty 
    WHERE  PropertyValue LIKE '%' + @SearchText+ '%'
    OR @SearchText = '*'
END
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @erikkallen allowing * to get all results and t* to get t related etc.

Comment: Have you run this, what was the challenge you were having? I think you are on the right path

Comment: Please look at the preview/your question when you post. Your three examples were all running together as a single "sentence" that made almost no sense. Use the formatting tools available.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not use:

```
WHERE  PropertyValue LIKE REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%');
```

The following test:

```
-- SAMPLE TABLE
DECLARE @T TABLE (A VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @T VALUES ('tea'), ('test'), ('foo'), ('bar'), ('foobar');

-- TEST USING WILDCARD AT END
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(100) = 't*';
SELECT  *
FROM    @T
WHERE   A LIKE REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%');

-- TEST USING ONLY WILD CARD
SET @SearchText = '*';
SELECT  *
FROM    @T
WHERE   A LIKE REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%');

--TEST USING WILD CARD AT START
SET @SearchText = '*bar';
SELECT  *
FROM    @T
WHERE   A LIKE REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%');

--TEST USING WILD CARD AT START AND END
SET @SearchText = '*a*';
SELECT  *
FROM    @T
WHERE   A LIKE REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%');
```

Outputs:

```
-- Wild card at end: "t*"
tea
test

-- Wild card only: "*"
tea
test
foo
bar
foobar

-- Wild card at start: "*bar"
bar
foobar

-- wild card at start and end: "*a*"
tea
bar
foobar
```

**EDIT**

I have just re-read your question, and seen the requirement that when no wild card characters are present to assume wild cards at both the start and the end, in which case you could add this to the start of the procedure:

```
IF CHARINDEX('*', @SearchText) = 0
    SET @SearchText = '%' + @SearchText + '%'
ELSE
    SET @SearchText = REPLACE(@SearchText, '*', '%')
```

then simply use

```
WHERE  PropertyValue LIKE @SearchText
```